# How to replace words with numbers in R studio in dataset

Tags: r, rstudio

I've seen a question similar to my own on here: "Replace specific column words into number or blank" but none of the solutions seemed to help my case.

What I'm trying to do is convert:

```
Question    Response
1           Sometimes
2           Almost Always
3           Sometimes
4           Almost Never
5           Often
```

into:

```
Question    Response
    1           2
    2           4
    3           2
    4           1
    5           3
```

Where Almost never = 1, sometimes = 2, often = 3, almost always = 4.

I imported the data via Excel, it is in a dataframe called STAI22 (I think).

I tried:

```
STAI22[STAI22$Response == "Almost never",]$Response = 1
STAI22[STAI22$Response == "sometimes",]$Response = 2
STAI22[STAI22$Response == "often",]$Response = 3
STAI22[STAI22$Response == "Almost always",]$Response = 4
```

but I got the error message:

```
 STAI22[STAI22$Response == "Almost Always",]$Response = "4"
Warning message:
In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, iseq, value = "4") :
  invalid factor level, NA generated
> STAI22[STAI22$Response == "Often",]$Response = "3"
Error in `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, STAI22$Response == "Often", , value = list( : 
  missing values are not allowed in subscripted assignments of data frames
> STAI22[STAI22$Response == "Sometimes",]$Response = "2"
Error in `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, STAI22$Response == "Sometimes", , value = list( : 
  missing values are not allowed in subscripted assignments of data frames
> STAI22[STAI22$Response == "Almost Never",]$Response = "1"
Error in `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, STAI22$Response == "Almost Never",  : 
  missing values are not allowed in subscripted assignments of data frames
```

and it did nothing to my data!

Comment: Just create a key/value data.frame and then merge with the original dataset

Comment: There is a discrepancy between your saying: *Where Almost never = 1, sometimes = 2, often = 3, almost always = 4.* and the table you have inserted

Comment: Following akrun's comment, you can do `lookup <- c("Almost Never" = 1, "Sometimes" = 2, "Often" = 3, "Almost Always" = 4)` and then for a data.frame named dat, `lookup[dat$Response]`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `case_when` from `dplyr`:

**dplyr version 0.5.0**

```
df <- read.table(text="Question    Response
1           Sometimes
2           'Almost Always'
3           Sometimes
4           'Almost Never'
5           Often",header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

library(dplyr)
df%>%
  mutate(Response=case_when(
    .$Response=="Sometimes" ~ 2,
    .$Response=="Almost Always" ~ 4,
    .$Response=="Almost Never" ~ 1,
    .$Response=="Often" ~ 3
      ))
  Question Response
1        1        2
2        2        4
3        3        2
4        4        1
5        5        3
```

**dplyr version 0.7.0**

```
df <- read.table(text="Question    Response
1           Sometimes
2           'Almost Always'
3           Sometimes
4           'Almost Never'
5           Often",header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

library(dplyr)
df%>%
  mutate(Response=case_when(
    Response=="Sometimes" ~ 2,
    Response=="Almost Always" ~ 4,
    Response=="Almost Never" ~ 1,
    Response=="Often" ~ 3
      ))
```

Comment: Yes! Thank you! This was great.

Answer (score 1):

YES! From working through a couple of various answers I finally managed to do it (for the sake of people who are as rubbish as me at R, I'm going to make a ridiculously simplified explanation of what I did):

I started with a data frame:

```
Question    Response
1           Somewhat
2           Very much so
3           Somewhat
4           Not at all
5           Moderately so
```

I created a look up table:

```
lookup <- c("Not at all" = 1, "Somewhat" = 2, "Moderately so" = 3, "Very much so" = 4)
```

Made a new column for my dataset:

```
Datasetname["Response2"] <- NA #Just fills the column with NA

Question    Response         Response2
1           Somewhat            NA
2           Very much so        NA
3           Somewhat            NA
4           Not at all          NA
5           Moderately so       NA
```

Then added the new values to that new column:

```
Datasetname$Response2 <- Datasetname[STAI$Response]

Question    Response            Response2
1           Somewhat            2
2           Very much so        4
3           Somewhat            2
4           Not at all          1
5           Moderately so       3
```

Hooray!

Thanks everyone for your suggestions - this way was the only one which worked for me for some reason (I was probably misunderstanding some of the suggestions)